# Hide the cell tag panel in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Jupyter notebook has a new feature of cell tags since version 5.0 as described in the [changelog](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog.html#notebook-version-5-0).

I activated the cell tags going to `View > Cell Toolbar` as described on their page.

How can I deactivate this little panel on the cells?
Pressing the same button again doesn't help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do the same process but this time just click `None`

[image]

Comment: amazing how simple it was... I'd have never found it as never checked what else is there... was perceiving them more as settings which get a tick next to them when activated

Comment: I'm using Jupter 6.0.3 and had to reload (F5) to make it work

Answer (score 0):

If last answer did not help, you also can edit .ipynb file code. in Jupyter - Home-running- stop your file, after that go to the explorer- click right bottom on your_file.ipynb open with notebook(just like .txt) - scroll down, find raw with "celltoolbar": "None", and delete this and save file, after run file in jupyter.